# Create a custom Query in Django 1.8

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-1.8

Consider below example:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()
    rental_date = models.DateTimeField() 
    rented_car = models.ForeignKey(Car)

class Car(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField()
    reg_no = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to group all rentals by car (assuming that a customer cannot rent more than one car but a customer can rent a car multiple times) and for each group return only the rental with the most recent `rental_date` and access the name of the customer and the car `reg_no`.

The SQL would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer c where rental_date = (SELECT max(rental_date) FROM Customer WHERE rented_car_id = c.rented_car_id);
```

or like this:

```
SELECT *, max(rental_date) from Customer group by rented_car;
```

The resulted query-set would then be sorted by customer first_name or car reg_no and other filters may be applied (for example, getting only the blue cars or customers whose name starts with 'A').

**Things that I have tried:**

Aggregation:

```
from django.db.models Max
Customer.objects.values('rented_car').annotate(max_start_date=Max('rental_date'))
```

but this returns a dict containing primary keys of `Car` objects. I would need values from `Customer` too. Modifying the query to include a field from `Customer` (`.values('rented_car', 'first_name')`) would change the SQL and alter the final result.

The second method I used is `raw`:

```
Customer.objects.raw("""SELECT * FROM Customer c where rental_date = (SELECT max(rental_date) FROM Customer WHERE rented_car_id = c.rented_car_id)""")
```

but this returns a RawQuerySet instance that does not allow further filtering or ordering. Also, `Customer.objects.filter(...).raw(...).order_by(...)` will not work as the `raw` method will override the filtering.

Another method that could return a query-set and allow extra filtering is `extra`:

```
Customer.objects.filter(...).extra(select={
    'customer_instances': """SELECT *, max(rental_date) from Customer group by rented_car"""
})
```

but his would always return an error `(1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')`. Also, from this [discussion](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24692) I found out that the QuerySet.extra(...) will no longer have support and `aggregation` should be used instead.

Comment: Your model / schema seems quite odd to me - I would have used an intermediate `Rent` model with the date and foreign keys on `Car` and `Customer` .

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, this is an analogy to a situation that I have on a project I am working on. Due to NDA agreements, I cannot give any more details, however, having another model would not be suitable.

Comment: Why would your project not accept a sane database design? Also, If you are under strict NDAs and stuff then there's money involved so hire a consultant that knows his way around Django and SQL and don't come here asking for other people to do your jobs for free.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I appreciate your approach and dedication.
Regarding the database design sanity, please let me assume that you are also a developer that has experience with complex projects, thus knowing that many projects suffer modifications especially in the final stages of the development. This is one of those situations.

Also, I am not asking for anyone to do my job for free, rather I presented an edge case in which Django would not be a good companion and maybe finding a workaround would help many others when developing complex applications.

Comment: Ergo, the edge case:

Having two related models (ModelA and ModelB), how could I group ModelA by a ModelB instance then cut the results per group having a special property without using custom SQL and being able to further filter the result (which means returning a Django QuerySet, not some RawQuerySet or some values in a dictionary)?

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't need custom SQL in Django. If you do find you are in trouble formulating your database queries with the ORM, consider if your database schema could be in a form that makes it easy (and efficient) for you to get your data.

You should probably [**normalize**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your rentals data into another table.

I've also normalized Color and Brand into their own models (and therefore tables) here because you will probably wish to seek by it and display a list of available Colors and Brands in your UI. If you allow your users to input Colors in the wild you will find yourself having a 1000 variations of "Blue" spelled in all kind of wrong ways in your Car model. Imagine searching from "Blue", "blue", "blues", "bLue" etc. and displaying that horrid stuff to your users. Eh...

Your car type (Sedan, Pickup, ...) would also, probably, be one table.

```
class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    hex = models.CharField(max_length=16)

class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)

class Car(models.Model): 
    # make sure your database constraints are thought-out
    reg_no = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    year = models.DateField()
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)

    class Meta:
        order_by = ('reg_no', )

class Customer(models.Model): 
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        order_by = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'pk')

class Rental(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()  # if it's a date, use a DateField
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)

    class Meta:
        # Let's not allow duplicate rentals for the same day
        unique_together = ('date', 'car')
        order_by = ('date', 'car', 'customer')

# Since your customers are already sorted by names,
# and your cars by 'reg_no', they follow that sorting.
# Your rentals are ordered by 'date' and therefore have the
# most recent date first in the table, so you can just select
# the most recent 'car' instances, which results in you getting
# the most recent 'car' rentals sorted by your dates,
# nice and easy:

Rental.objects.all().distinct('car')

# Pretty easy to search your rentals now.
# If you want to filter just use something like:

Rental.objects.filter(
    date__range=(datetime(2016, 1, 1), datetime(2017, 1, 1),
    car__brand__icontains='Toyota',
    customer__first_name__icontains='John'
)
```

In Django you can usually figure out what your schema should look like by looking into your product and figuring out what kind of abstractions you have there. You seem to have at least Users, Cars, Rentals and Colors here.

You might also find the [**django-filter**](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter) package useful here. It plays well with your UI and possible API, if you will be constructing one.